# Installing man pages for Fedora cloud

Tags: fedora, man, dnf, cloud

I have installed a Fedora cloud image for education purposes. It has no man pages but I want them.

[Gergely Gombos](https://github.com/gombosg) writes a solution at the [fedora-cloud issues page](https://github.com/fedora-cloud/docker-brew-fedora/issues/9):

> Workaround solution for later reference: comment `tsflags=nodocs`
> in `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf`, then reinstall *everything* with
>
> ```
> sudo dnf reinstall $(sudo dnf list --installed | awk '{print $1})
> ```

Is there an easier solution than reinstalling all packages?

Comment: Are you [gombosg](https://github.com/gombosg)?  I’m not sure whether this case is covered by the rules (it’s certainly ***not*** plagiarism if you quote yourself), but we encourage people to disclose when they are linking to their own work.

Comment: I'm not gombosg.

Answer (score 2):

Install the following packages:

```
sudo dnf install man-pages man-db man
mandb
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not an easier method of getting your man pages than reinstalling the packages for which you want man pages. Those man pages are part of the package itself, so to get them you need to reinstall the package.